# Checked out documents in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, checkout

Good day,

Please help, I am working on SharePoint 2013 and a user wants to know all the document that she has checked out on the entire SharePoint site not only on one Library, how can I achieve this?.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the below PowerShell script to list the checked-out files from one site collection:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell –EA 0

$SiteUrl="http://sp/sites/sitename/"
$Report="c:\temp\checked-outfilesreport.csv"
    
#Get the site collection 
$site=Get-SPSite $SiteUrl

#Write the CSV Header - Tab Separated
"Site Collection Name `t Site Name`t Library `t File Name `t File URL `t  Last Modified `t Checked-Out By" | Out-file $Report
        
#Loop through each site in the site collection
ForEach($Web in $Site.AllWebs){
     #Loop through each document library
     Foreach ($List in $Web.GetListsOfType([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary)){
         #Get only Document Libraries
         if ($List.Hidden -eq $false){
             #Loop through each Item
             foreach($ListItem in $List.Items){
                 If( ($ListItem.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") -and ($ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser -ne $null)){
                     #Log the data to a CSV file
                     "$($Site.RootWeb.Title) `t $($Web.Title) `t $($List.Title) `t $($ListItem.Name) `t $($Web.Url)/$($ListItem.Url) `t  $($ListItem['Modified'].ToString()) `t  $($ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser)" | Out-File $Report -Append
                 }
             }
             Write-Host "Successfully!"
         }
     }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there anything else I can help with regarding this issue? If the answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below PowerShell script to find the checked-out files.

```
#Add PowerShell Snapin
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Function to find CheckedOutFiles
Function CheckedOutFiles()
{ 
#Define 'Web Application URL' as Mandatory Parameter
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$WebAppURL,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ReportOutput
)

#Get the Web Application
$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

#Write the CSV Header - Tab Separated
"Site Collection Name `t Site Name`t Library `t File Name `t File URL `t  Last Modified `t Checked-Out By" | Out-file $ReportOutput

#Arry to Skip System Lists and Libraries
$SystemLists =@("Converted Forms", "Master Page Gallery", "Customized Reports", "Form Templates", "List Template Gallery", "Theme Gallery",
       "Reporting Templates", "Solution Gallery", "Style Library", "Web Part Gallery","Site Assets", "wfpub")

#Loop through each site collection
ForEach($Site in $WebApp.Sites)
{
    #Loop through each site in the site collection
    ForEach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
    {
        Write-host "Processing Site:" $web.Url
        #Loop through each document library
        Foreach ($List in $Web.GetListsOfType([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary))
        {
            #Get only Document Libraries & Exclude Hidden System libraries
            if ( ($List.Hidden -eq $false) -and ($SystemLists -notcontains $List.Title) )
            {
                #Loop through each Item
                foreach ($ListItem in $List.Items)
                {
                    If( ($ListItem.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") -and ($ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser -ne $null))
                    {
                        #Log the data to a txt file
                        "$($Site.RootWeb.Title) `t $($Web.Title) `t $($List.Title) `t $($ListItem.Name) `t $($Web.Url)/$($ListItem.Url) `t  $($ListItem['Modified'].ToString()) `t  $($ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser)" | Out-File $ReportOutput -Append
                        Write-host -f Yellow "Found a Checked out file at: $($Web.Url)/$($ListItem.Url)"
   

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Send message to output console
write-host -f Green "Checked out Files Report Generated Successfully!"
}

   #Call the Function to Get Checked-Out Files
 CheckedOutFiles -WebAppURL "<your sharepoint site>" -ReportOutput "C:\CheckedOutReport.txt"
```